# Do I need to pay for a second hobby dyno to run worker processes when using Heroku?

Tags: heroku, vapor

I am currently using a Hobby dyno to run my web process -- frontend website as well as an API. To execute jobs, I need to run a background process that processes these jobs. Do I need to spin up another dyno that specifically runs background workers? I ask this because I see that Standard 1X/2x dynos include "unlimited background workers" which makes me think that multiple process types can run on a single dyno. It looks like I can run 2 hobby dynos -- one for web, one for workers or upgrade to one of the standard dynos...is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that yes, if you want to have a dedicated worker app, that needs to be a separate dyno. You can run the processes in memory though and that saves you doing it with a separate binary/dyno

Comment: This makes sense, and I believe what I do locally when I execute: try app.queues.startInProcessJobs(on: .default). I just need to add this to my configure file to be executed when Heroku builds my app?